# Given $R$ and its eigenvalues, find the eigenvalues of $R + 2I$:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem solving an exercice, that I expose in the following.

*Let $\textbf{R}$ be a $3\times3$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda = \{-4,-2,\ 2\}$. What are the eigenvalues of $\textbf{R} + 2\textbf{I}$ with $\textbf{I}$ the identity matrix?*

My answer is that, given that
$$det(\textbf{R} -\lambda\textbf{I})$$

and that 
$$det(\textbf{R} + 2\textbf{I}-\lambda\textbf{I})  = det(\textbf{R}  -\textbf{I}(\lambda-2))$$
I assume that for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\textbf{R}$, there is an eigen value $\lambda '$ of $\textbf{R} + 2\textbf{I}$ such that 
$$\lambda ' = \lambda - 2$$
and therefore
$$\lambda' = \{-6,-4,\ 0\}$$

which I'm said it's not correct. Why?

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial and $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $R$, then $p(\lambda_j)$ are the eigenvalues of $p(R)$. To see this: just consider the definition $Rv=\lambda_j v$.

Comment: Just a sign error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $\mathbf{R}$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, that is, $\mathbf{R} v = \lambda v$. Then
$$
(\mathbf{R} + 2 \mathbf{I}) v
=
\mathbf{R} v + 2 \mathbf{I} v
=
\lambda v + 2 v
=
(\lambda + 2) v,
$$
which tells you that $v$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{R} + 2 \mathbf{I}$ with respect to the eigenvalue...

---

The correct calculation you were doing is the following. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{R}$, then
$$
0
=
\det(\mathbf{R} - \lambda \mathbf{I})
=
\det(\mathbf{R} +  2 \mathbf{I} - 2 \mathbf{I} - \lambda \mathbf{I})
=
\det(\mathbf{R} +  2 \mathbf{I} - (\lambda + 2) \mathbf{I}),
$$
so that $\lambda + 2$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{R} + 2 \mathbf{I}$.

Comment: Very clarifying. What a silly mistake I made employing twice $\lambda$ to talk about different sets of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be an Eigenvalue of $R$,

$$\text{det}(R-\lambda I)=0$$

and $\mu$ an Eigenvalue of the modified matrix,

$$\text{det}(R+2I-\mu I)=\text{det}(R-(\mu-2) I)=0.$$

Then, $\mu=\lambda+2$.

Comment: Let me tell you I find your answer as helpful as the one I marked as **the** answer. Thank you.